# Unable to Update the suptitle string with text value

Tags: python, matplotlib-widget

I am trying to putdown the strign value from the text field to the string in the mplwidget suptitle but it is not working.

```
 te = (self.a1.text())
  self.MplWidget.canvas.figure.suptitle("Thermo Physical Properties of "+te)
```

Answer (score 0):

U need to cast to a variable as follows  to get the value in to suptitle

```
     val = (self.a1.text())
     val2 = str(te)
     self.MplWidget.canvas.figure.suptitle("Thermo Physical Properties of " + val2)
```